# Delete Historical Events in MixPanel

Tags: mixpanel

I recently created a MixPanel analytics account and have added a bunch of unneeded events for development/learning purposes.

Is there a way to delete all events associated with a MixPanel project, or to delete all events associated with a user profile?

Answer (score 14):

Technically, [events data is immutable in Mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com/help/questions/articles/can-i-delete-or-hide-events-and-properties-from-my-project) and you cannot delete it. You have a couple of options:

A) If you don't have any valuable user on your Mixpanel account so far, it's fastest to just discard everything by creating a new Mixpanel project and starting from scratch. From the project selector menu, click "Create new project". Delete the old one or just ignore it.

B) You can also hide your existing events by name (Settings > Project Settings > Data management > [add events to hide]). This will hide all the events with the given names from the UI. You can use this option if it is OK for you to pick new names for events that you want to track in the future.

(You can also delete the profiles which have unwanted events associated to them. But as events data is immutable, this probably won't stop these events from showing up in event-based views like Segmentation or Insights, unless you filter them in a way that presumes an associated profile to exist. Use the UI or `$delete` operation in the [HTTP API](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/http#update-operations) to delete profiles.)

Comment: This is a really strange behaviour. We it's designed like that?